# How to express special font characters in equations in Latex?

Tags: equations, pdftex, mathcal

Would anyone have a suggestion on how to express special font characters, i.e.

```
\mathcal{H}_{0}
```

In a subscript in an equation?  The result is an italic representation, but I want the normal 'mathcal' representation.

Comment: The same way you'd express it anywhere else? E.g., `$x = A_{\mathcal{H}_{0}}$` What problem are you having? Where and how are you getting an "italic representation"?

Comment: in general in questions here please always include a complete small document that shows the problem you are asking about